# getElementById is not working for the div which is inside of tabset

Tags: javascript

this is my html

```
<div>
<h1 class="main-header logic-head  av-settings-head"></h1>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 tabcontent" >
    <form class="form-horizontal formtext col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-lg-10 row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-3 paddnone">
                <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input id="NewobjectName" type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-3 paddnone">
                <label class="control-label">Description</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-5 paddnone">
                <textarea id="objectDescription" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-3 paddnone">
                <label class="control-label">Type</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-5 paddnone">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>M</option>
                    <option>C</option>
                    <option>CM</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-3 paddnone">
                <label class="control-label">IsActive</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="checkbox" checked="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-3 paddnone">
                <label class="control-label">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>             
            <!-- Groups Area Tables Start -->
            <div class="row">

                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab_bg">
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->

                    <div tabset justified="true" ng-if="clientScript.specification=='commonSpecific'">

                        <div tab heading="ClientScript">
                            <div class="tab-content pad25 users-area">
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane mart15 active" id="objectPermissions">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-3 paddnone">
                                            <label class="control-label">Javascript Type</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-5 paddnone">
                                            <select class="form-control" ng-change="onEventChange(script.event)" ng-options="obj.eventName as obj.label for obj in events"
                                                    ng-model="script.event">
                                                <option value="">-select event-</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="method-tab" id="method-tab">
                                        <div class="row form-group btnbg">
                                            <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-12">
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">ADD +</button>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 well pad0">
                                            <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
                                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs method-right">
                                                    <li class="active"><i></i><a href="#name" data-toggle="tab">Script 1</a></li>
                                                    <li class=""><i></i><a data-toggle="tab" href="#group-2">Script 2</a></li>
                                                    <li class=""><i></i><a href="#group-3" data-toggle="tab">Script 3</a></li>
                                                    <li class=""><i></i><a href="#group-4" data-toggle="tab">Script 4</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="tab-content content-left">
                                                    <div class="tab-pane col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-12 pad0 marl19 active" id="name">
                                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                            <h4>Javascript Editor</h4>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                            <div class="panel panel-default">

                                                                <div class="panel-body min-height">
                                                                    <div id="editor">
                                                            function foo(items) {
                                                                var i;
                                                                for (i = 0; i &lt; items.length; i++) {
                                                                    alert("Ace Rocks " + items[i]);
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                            </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row form-group btnbg">
                                            <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-12">
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">SAVE</button>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button id="saveObject" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()">
                                    Validate
                                </button>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div tab heading="SQL">

                        </div>
                        <div tab heading="HTML">

                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-lg-7  btnbg">
                <button id="saveObject" class="btn btn-primary " ng-click="save()">
                    SAVE
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and i am finding the element by id which is inside of tabset and that id name is "editor" but it is giving null

and my .js code is
`var element=document.getElementById("editor");`

the div with id "editor" is inside of tabset so i think that would be reason why it couldn't find it...so what would be the alternate method to handle this?

Comment: What happens when you log element to the console? Also, it's difficult to know what the problem is without seeing the js.

Comment: Also, in javascript assign your variables with var in front of them

Comment: why is there `javascript` code within your `editor` div..?

Comment: In my .js is straight forward it just have that one code line, but when i find it is giving me null

Comment: Make sure your javascript is placed *after* the HTML to which it refers. Or, better yet, place your javascript in a ready handler to make sure that the DOM is ready when you try to access it.

Comment: Actually i am using ace module for javascript editor

Comment: Hi Syed I checked code and able to access div Id

Comment: Still...if you need to place your `javascript` code place it inside `script` tag.. it won't work this way..

Comment: @SunnyS.M but how ? i am getting null here!!!

Comment: It return object, can explain what output you expected ? and what you want do with that div id

Comment: @SyedRasheed It is very important where you place your javascript. Where is it?

Comment: my javascript is placed in seperate .js file and in that i wrote `var element=document.getElementById("editor");`

Comment: ...but where is your <script> tag? Do you understand that you can't access the DOM until it is ready?

Comment: @LeeTaylor its just a code  which is placed inside of div tag and when i run that i get that code inside of "javascript editor"(ace module) throught that div id i am getting the content inside of div tag!!!!! do u get me now???

Comment: yes, but if you're trying to access your element (using getElementById) then this must be placed **after** where the element is placed. Is it?

Comment: can u write plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is working properly

```js
var element =  document.getElementById("editor");
snippet.log(element)
snippet.log(element.innerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1 class="main-header logic-head  av-settings-head"></h1>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 tabcontent">
    <form class="form-horizontal formtext col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-lg-10 row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-3 paddnone">
          <label class="control-label">Name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input id="NewobjectName" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-3 paddnone">
          <label class="control-label">Description</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-5 paddnone">
          <textarea id="objectDescription" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-3 paddnone">
          <label class="control-label">Type</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-5 paddnone">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>M</option>
            <option>C</option>
            <option>CM</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-3 paddnone">
          <label class="control-label">IsActive</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input type="checkbox" checked="true" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-3 paddnone">
          <label class="control-label">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <!-- Groups Area Tables Start -->
        <div class="row">

          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab_bg">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->

            <div tabset justified="true" ng-if="clientScript.specification=='commonSpecific'">

              <div tab heading="Scocu ClientScript">
                <div class="tab-content pad25 users-area">
                  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane mart15 active" id="objectPermissions">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-3 paddnone">
                        <label class="control-label">Javascript Type</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-5 paddnone">
                        <select class="form-control" ng-change="onEventChange(script.event)" ng-options="obj.eventName as obj.label for obj in events" ng-model="script.event">
                          <option value="">-select event-</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="method-tab" id="method-tab">
                      <div class="row form-group btnbg">
                        <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-12">
                          <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">ADD +</button>
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 well pad0">
                        <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
                          <ul class="nav nav-tabs method-right">
                            <li class="active"><i></i><a href="#name" data-toggle="tab">Script 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=""><i></i><a data-toggle="tab" href="#group-2">Script 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=""><i></i><a href="#group-3" data-toggle="tab">Script 3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=""><i></i><a href="#group-4" data-toggle="tab">Script 4</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                          <div class="tab-content content-left">
                            <div class="tab-pane col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-12 pad0 marl19 active" id="name">
                              <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <h4>Javascript Editor</h4>
                              </div>
                              <div class="clearfix"></div>
                              <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">

                                  <div class="panel-body min-height">
                                    <div id="editor">
                                      function foo(items) { var i; for (i = 0; i &lt; items.length; i++) { alert("Ace Rocks " + items[i]); } }
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row form-group btnbg">
                        <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-12">
                          <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">SAVE</button>
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <button id="saveObject" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()">
                    Validate
                  </button>

                </div>

              </div>
              <div tab heading="Scocu SQL">

              </div>
              <div tab heading="Scocu HTML">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-lg-7  btnbg">
          <button id="saveObject" class="btn btn-primary " ng-click="save()">
            SAVE
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the value inside the div use

```
var element=document.getElementById("editor");
alert(element.innerHTML);
```

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/w34aL9gb/)

Comment: once you inculde bootstrap.js for tabset it won't work